# Make Thin Mould

Tags: modifiers, scale

I am very new to blender so go easy on me. I have a model I want to cast in cement for this is obviously need a mould. The plan is to make this in blender and then 3D print it. I know about Boolean operations and adding a cube around my model and subtracting the model. The problem here is however that such a mould becomes very big wastes a lot of plastic and takes a long time to print. What I want instead is a mould that is let's say 5 mm thick everywhere. Is there a good way to make this (note that simply scaling will not work if the model is not convex)?

I have had some success with sculpting and using different tools there to make a larger (almost) copy of my model and then subtracting the original model from this (see picture). But this results in a model of uneven thickness and is quite time consuming and imprecise. Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Mould of a hand]

Comment: How about the solidify modifier?

Comment: Not sure but "Shrink/Fatten" seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol this is embarrassing. I found the perfect tool. There is a tool in Layout mode (is it called a mode?) called "Shrink/Fatten" which does exactly what I want. It will take all surfaces of your model and in a sense extrude them in a reasonable direction. I do not know how well it will work on more complex models though. I guess time will tell.

Thanks anyway!