# Thick Skin Model

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm super new to Blender and I realise there is already something called a skin but all words I can think of to describe what I want to do are already features in Blender. I'll do my best to describe the idea simply.

What I want to do, simply put, is to create an offset from my model (a thick skin in a sense). This can, to some extent, be done with the fatten functionality but with more advanced models this creates weird overlapping geometry.

I imagine something that takes a sphere of a certain radius, sweeps its center over and inside the entire model and makes a new object from the points that it swept over. So another way of seeing this is to create a new body which encloses all points a certain distance or less from the original object.

Is this at all possible? The reason I want to do this is to create a thin mould of my object, exactly like what I was trying to do over a year ago [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154810/make-thin-mould). I thought I had figured it out with the fatten feature but I was wrong.

Thanks for any help!

----------EDIT----------

Thank you for your suggestions so far, unfortunately neither of these work though. In the picture below you can see the issue I am encountering. When the model has a tight curvature or a crease the faces on either side of the crease overlap and create an internal fold. This means that I would have to go through the model and remove all of these folds manually. I am not very good at Blender so first of all I am not sure how to do this properly but also this seems like bad practice (I might be wrong and maybe I should just stop complaining and put in the work.). Anyway, I have also added my file if anyone wants to experience my frustration first hand.

[image]

Blend-Exchange didn't work unfortunately. Here is the file anyway: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VWbNDGIzD-W00Hkki5BQLbJHqLQzEFPm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you try the Solidify modifier as suggested in the previous question you asked?

Comment: Or displace modifier

Comment: @JohnEason - Unfortunately this doesn't work and it actually creates the exact same issue as fattening. In the creases of my model I get intersecting geometry which is not 3D-printable. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Gorgious - This creates the same issue again.

Comment: Use a remesh modifier afterwards set to voxel. Be careful not setting the value too low or blender will crash